# php regex to preg_replace dots in string,but dot(s) in possible floats

Tags: regex

```
$string = "Some words here. More words, followed by 1.5 and 2.3 here.Here is no space after the dot."
```

I need to add the white space after the dot between sentences (if there is no one), but don't change dots in floats.

```
$result = "Some words here. More words, followed by 1.5 and 2.3 here. Here is no space after the dot."
```

Was "here.Here"
Became "here. Here"

Tried a lot, but can't find the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it...

```
preg_replace('/([a-z]+)\.([^\s])/i', '$1. $2', $string);
```